# Are all integrals of the from “polynomial1 divided by polynomial 2” solvable?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm asking whether all integrals of the form "polynomial 1 of degree n" divided by "polynomial 2 of degree m" are solvable for all values of n and m and for all coefficients of polynomial 1 and 2. If not, is there a formula that tells you which integral is unsolvable and which is solvable?

Comment: no formula.   Partial fractions does depend on factoring the denominator, and this gets impossible for some polynomials of degree 5 or more, and extremely difficult in some cases of degrees 3,4

Comment: If we know the roots (or factorization) of the denominator, then yes—but as Will Jagy says, finding that information can be difficult. (Numerical approximations are always available.) The functions you refer to (quotients of polynomials) are called "rational functions".

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int \frac{p_{1}()}{p_{2}()} $$
This all depends on the characteristics of $p_{1}, p_{2}$ and their relationship, degree of $p_{1}$ is $n$, and degree of $p_{2}$ is $m$

If $n \gt m $, use $ P = D \dot Q + R$ to re-express and integrate to get the new function, which would be a polynomial of degree $n-m+1$, the new polynomial $n-m+1$ is unique, can be solvable or not

But if the *Reminder* on division is not a number, but another polynomial, the process here is different involves partial fraction and the results is not always polynomial but some logarithmic function

If $n \gt m $, result is not a polynomial, let's not speak of solving